# Swagger PHP & OA3 - How to hide some endoint/controllers (zircote/swagger-php)

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, openapi-generator

I'm using zircote/swagger-php with OA3 annotation in a laravel project,
**There is a way to temporarily hide a method or a controller**?

As alternative:
I've some api controller which is "more internal" and others more "public domain",  my current compilation command is:

```
./vendor/bin/openapi --output ./public/api/swagger.json --exclude vendor ./app/Http/Controllers/API/
```

there is a way to build 2 different json, one to be "used locally" that list all endpoints and another to be used "in production" that omit some endpoints?